# How to exit from nested if-else statements inside a for loop?(C/C++)

Tags: c++, for-loop, break, goto, nested-if

I have a `for` loop in my program that is my program's main loop and it should work in real time. There are some `if-else` statements inside the loop too. I want if any `if` conditions satisfied, the program exits from `if-else` statements and retry the for loop.

```
for(;;)
{
    if(condition_one)
    {
        do_one();
    }
    else if(condition_two)
    {
        do_two();
    }
    else 
    {
        do_three();
    }

    rest_of_program();
}
```

I tried to write the above code like this:

```
for(;;)
{
    if(condition_one)
    {
        do_one();
        goto exitt; 
    }
    else if(condition_two)
    { 
        do_two();
        goto exitt;
    }
    else 
    {
        do_three(); 
    }
    exitt:
    rest_of_program();
}
```

But it seems there is a problem and my program doesn't work! Did I do something wrong? Or is there a better idea?

Comment: Are you looking for `continue`, `goto`, `return`? It's a bit hard to tell..

Comment: not clear... "I want if each if conditions satisfied, the program exits from if-else statements and retry the for loop." what your first code does is: No matter what conditions are satisfied the if-else statement is left and the for loop continues with the next iteration

Comment: ahh... you mean "if **any** of the conditions is satisfied" ?

Comment: Sorry, I will try to edit to be more clear

Comment: As of now, it's not clear why you need the goto's at all. In your example, things should work the way you want them to in the first piece of code you posted.

Comment: From the description it seems like you want to use `continue`.

Comment: i have the feeling that what you want is just the way a plain if-else works. no need for anything special (definitely no need for `goto`)

Comment: Both snippets do the same thing, since the `goto` as at the end of each branch and the label is immediately after the `else` branch.

Comment: You are asking for *EACH* if statement to be satisfied, then return to the loop? I imagine that would be to simple check for both first with an IF statement which checks for both.

Comment: perhaps you can add some `cout`s in the branches and show expected vs actual output?

Comment: Just to clarify: He wants to check if **all** conditions are satisfied, right?

Comment: There are no *nested* `if` statements there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating the matter. The thing is that this code:

```
for(;;)
{
    if(condition_one)
    {
        do_one();
        goto exitt; 
    }
    else if(condition_two)
    { 
        do_two();
        goto exitt;
    }
    else 
    {
        do_three(); 
    }
    exitt:
    rest_of_program();
}
```

is equivalent to this one:

```
for(;;)
{
    if(condition_one)
    {
        do_one();
    }
    else if(condition_two)
    { 
        do_two();
    }
    else 
    {
        do_three(); 
    }
    rest_of_program();
}
```

The individual blocks of the `if-else` are mutually exclusive and no matter which one is executed, after that there will be `rest_of_program` and after that the loop continues.

Comment: Does that answer the question though? I'm kind of confused what he's asking too, but I'm pretty sure he's looking to return to the for loop in the event of both if statements being satisfied.

Comment: @CillianCollins i am trying a parallel strategy, asking for clarifications in comments and writing an answer based on my current understanding at the same time, lets see where this goes ;)

Comment: Ahh fair enough. Hope you do update your post as we get more clarification though! I was assuming you were dropping it and leaving without an answer haha.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you try a new IF statement, and put it at the top of your for loop?

```
for(;;)
{
if(condition_one && condition_two){
    continue
}
else if(condition_one)
{do_one();}
else if(condition_two)
{do_two();}
else {do_three();}

rest_of_program();
}
```

I think this is basically what you're asking for. You check if both are satisfied and then return to your loop, otherwise you continue to check your list.

By the way, **MUCH BETTER WAYS** of doing this than using goto, but I haven't seen your full code so it's difficult to make a solution which would work.

**EDIT**: As pointed out by user463035818 below, a `continue` will work in place of the goto. I was a bit confused at first but he is right, it will skip the current iteration.

Comment: just put a `continue` in place of the `goto`

Comment: He wants to repeat the forloop though, not continue. If he continues then he is using something which will satisy BOTH condition and probably will mess up his program. He wants to restart the program, and I image the forloop will change when he goes back to it. As it's a forloop, it will have something like a '++' which will increment his value each iteration.

Comment: repeating a `for(;;)` is exactly the same as just `continue` with the "next" iteration, really no need for `goto` here

Comment: I don't like the practice of using a `goto` as mentioned in my OP, but I felt like there was too little information to try an alternate solution based on what OP wrote, which was a script with a bunch of goto. Hopefully we get more clarification along with some more code to make the assumption you're making. But I don't think we can assume that `continue` is fit for purpose in this circumstance, can we?

Comment: just dont assume, but take the code as posted by OP, anything else is speculation

Comment: Apologies you are right, I was a bit confused with what you meant but `continue` is fit for purpose in this circumstance.

Comment: no need to apologize, i am glad if your confusion is cleared now :)

Answer (score 1):

Since it hasn't been mentioned, there is also the option of using a [`continue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/continue) statement to reset to the start of the loop *without* immediately exiting. Note that this *will* execute the iterator statement in a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `break` statement. It will exit the `for` loop:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/break